# C++ won't print trailing whitespace

Tags: c++

In my simple program to learn C++, I am asking the user their name and then greeting them.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}
```

However, here is my result in CLion:

[image]

I expected the program to print out a trailing whitespace after the prompt for my name. However, it prints the space *after* I give the program input. I have only experienced this in CLion, but not in other IDEs. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to flush your stream:

```
std::cout << "Enter your name: " << std::flush;
```

`std::cout` is a buffered stream which means that while your write to it isn't immediately written to the underlying device, but it is stored in a buffer. This is done for performance reasons. `std::endl` has an implicit flush operation, that's why you don't notice this if you always add a `std::endl` before you request input. Otherwise, like you've seen that can happen.

Comment: @EvanZhao make sure you compile and run the new binary. It will work.

Comment: It worked! However... while running the .exe file works, running the program in CLion won't work.

Comment: @EvanZhao maybe there's a problem with the way CLion handles the console. I honestly don't know.